# Google test ads fail to load

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I am trying to integrate interstitial ads in certain parts of my app, but, when using the google test ad ID, I always get the "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet." message. I thought that since I am using test ads, not real ads, I shouldn't be having this problem.

For the ad unit ID, I used the interstitial ad test ID from [google](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads), and for the App ID, I added my app to AdMob and copy & pasted the id into AndroidManifest.xml, following Google's instructions on [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) page. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

interstitial  ads take time to load after calling  `mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());`

its better to wait to load for ads. and how the ad when its loaded https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#ad_events

```
@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
}
```

Here is Googles provided example You can follow it
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/admob/InterstitialExample

Comment: I opened the app and left it running for over an hour, and got the same result. The ads didn't load. Is it supposed to take that long?

Comment: No ,  only needs a few seconds if the internet connection is good

Comment: One more thing please check your project have internet permission or not

Comment: I added these two lines to AndroidManifest.xml:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

The problem is still happening. Is there something else I need to do to ensure internet access of the app in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection in your virtual device.

Comment: this is better off as a comment rather than an answer